# Jquery slideToggle, slideUp & stopPropagation in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am using jquery slidetoggle & slideup so that, when a user clicks on #link, #div (which is by default hidden) slides open. Additionally, any click anywhere should slideUp and hide #div. So my script is like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click(function(){
        $('#div').slideToggle('fast');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(window).click(function() {
        $('#div').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

This works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox the initial click to open the div also triggers the slideUp, so the div slides down and then immediately slides back up. What am I doing wrong here? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: bind an event click for window object when you have others click events is something weird for me. I would redesign that behavior. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have missed to pass `event` object to the listener.Correct your code to this and try..

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#link').click(function(event){ //note here
        $('#div').slideToggle('fast');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(window).click(function() {
        $('#div').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

for more details refer here [event.stopPropogation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

hope this helps!

Comment: That works, but why did it work for Chrome beforehand? Does Chrome handle j/s in a fundamentally different way than FF?

Comment: on the line event.stopPropogation event object is null,so it can't stop propogation.And yeah different browsers have little handling differences @pg.